# comparing one column of a text file with a value using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file with following details:

```
282685884BG      10 A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     12/4/2013 9:03:58 AM            12/4/2013 9:07:27 AM              18
282686035BJ      5  A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     12/4/2013 9:03:58 AM            12/4/2013 9:07:27 AM              240
282686105BG      5  A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     12/4/2013 9:03:58 AM            12/4/2013 9:07:27 AM              330
282686106BI      5  A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     12/4/2013 9:03:58 AM            12/4/2013 9:07:27 AM              4440
```

I want to compare the last column values which is greater than 300. 
So, my out should show like below:

```
282686105BG      5  A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     12/4/2013 9:03:58 AM            12/4/2013 9:07:27 AM              330
282686106BI      5  A_DEL_OPT_AUTH            33VANC     12/4/2013 9:03:58 AM            12/4/2013 9:07:27 AM              4440
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this using shell script commands?

Answer (score 2):

A simple [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script can do that:

```
awk '$(NF)>300 { print }'
```

`NF` is the number of fields, `$(NF)` gives you the last column, if it is larger than 300, then we print the whole line.

Comment: `awk '$NF > 300'` will suffice.  Printing is the default action.